# What is the right way of avoiding long interface block in every subroutine in a FORTRAN code?

Tags: fortran

I need to write this interface block on every subroutine that uses solvmatrx:

```
      INTERFACE
      SUBROUTINE solvmatrx( x0, ABRS_, nstp, ad00, alu00, b, lnt00, lnd00, nd, ns00, &
                      mstEp, eps, lop1, lu0sw, rto, irtc,  LPV, LPM, NV, LEPSSW, OMG, &
                      GAMMA_, LCOLOR_, PARALLEL)
          integer*4 nd, ns00, nv, ndb, ndx, irtc, nstp, mstep, lepssw, lop1, lu0sw
          integer*4 lnd00(ND), lnt00(NS00), lpv(ND), lpm(ND), LCOLOR_
          real*8    x0(ND),b(ND),ad00(ND),alu00(NS00),ABRS_,eps,rto,omg,GAMMA_
          LOGICAL, INTENT(IN), optional :: PARALLEL
      END SUBROUTINE solvmatrx
  END INTERFACE
```

How do I avoid this?

Comment: Other than obvious choices, such as putting this in a MODULE mymod so you can simply USE mymod ?

Comment: Many observers rightly prefer that you quote standard Fortran syntax such as integer(int32), real(real64) or Fortran 90 alternative in place of the old IBM360 non-standard stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the obvious should be written out explicitly.

You rarely need interface blocks in Fortran 90. Nine times out of ten using an interface block means you are doing something wrong. You should use modules.

1. `solvmatrix` itself should be in a module.
2. If it is not, because it is in some kind of legacy external library, then the interface block should be in a module.

   ```
   MODULE INTERFACES

     INTERFACE
       SUBROUTINE solvmatrx( x0, ABRS_, nstp, ad00, alu00, b, lnt00, lnd00, nd, ns00, &
                     mstEp, eps, lop1, lu0sw, rto, irtc,  LPV, LPM, NV, LEPSSW, OMG, &
                     GAMMA_, LCOLOR_, PARALLEL)
         integer*4 nd, ns00, nv, ndb, ndx, irtc, nstp, mstep, lepssw, lop1, lu0sw
         integer*4 lnd00(ND), lnt00(NS00), lpv(ND), lpm(ND), LCOLOR_
         real*8    x0(ND),b(ND),ad00(ND),alu00(NS00),ABRS_,eps,rto,omg,GAMMA_
         LOGICAL, INTENT(IN), optional :: PARALLEL
       END SUBROUTINE solvmatrx
     END INTERFACE

   END MODULE
   ```

and then just in every subroutine, or **much better**, in the module which contains all the subroutines

```
 USE INTERFACES
```